# Can't understand the update of b value in SMO algorithm for SVM

Tags: algorithms

I just read Patt's paper "Fast Training of Support Vector Machines
using Sequential Minimal Optimization" ,solving the QP problem on alpha and b for SVM. I am confused about the update process of b value.

In the paper, page 8, subtitle "The Threshold and the Error Cache".

> When both b1 and b2 are valid, they are equal. When both new Lagrange
>   multipliers are at bound and if L is not equal to H, then the interval
>   between b1 and b2 are all thresholds that are consistent with the KKT
>   conditions. In this case, SMO chooses the threshold to be halfway in
>   between b1 and b2.

Why b1=b2 when they are both valid? And why does the interval between b1 and b2 fit the KKT conditions?

PS:Is the equation (12.11) calculating the Ek*new* in the paper wrong? I think the last two terms in the equation should be b*new*-b*old* while it is b*old*-b*new*.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it by now?